# grep and sed string with [ ] - search and replace text:[xxxxxxxx]

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I want to delete all *"tags":[xxxxx]* array in a JSON text string
e.g.  "aaa":"bbb","tags":[abcdefg],"ccc":"ddd"

I used grep to get the regular expression right

1. tried this: `grep \"tags\":\[.*\]`    ==> this didn't work
2. tried this: `grep \"tags\":\\[.*\]`   ==> this works

to escape the `[` character in grep command, why two `\` is required?

then I tried to use sed to replace "tags":[abcdefg]

```
sed s/\"tags\":\\[.*\]//g
```

it does not work.

Can someone give suggestion?

Comment: You have to format your code, either on a separate line with four spaces indentation or with backticks (`\``). It's impossible to tell how many backslashes you meant to put there. Also, you probably want to use a JSON parser such as jq, not grep/sed/awk.

Comment: post your input json

Comment: Use `sed 's/"tags":\\\[.*]//g`

Comment: Sorry, first time stackoverflow user.  I did notice weird display of / character in preview when I write this question yesterday.  I just edited it

Comment: Wiktor, thanks.   the 3 backslashes works !